# How to remove a bullet on an empty li element

Tags: jquery

```
/HTML/
<ul id="list" class="row list-group checked-list-box col-xs-3"></ul>
/append li tag/
 $('#list').append('<li class="list-group-item tree">  <input type="checkbox"  name="swt">'+ "Train" + '</li>');
/Jquery/
var sw = {};
    var favorite = [];
    $.each($("input[name='swt']:checked"), function() {
        favorite.push($(this).val());           
    });
    sw.swd = favorite;

var skill= {};
    for (var m = 0; m < favorite.length; m++) {
        var swObj = [];
        $.each($('input[name="' + sw.swd[m] + '"]:checked'), function() {                
            swObj.push($(this).attr("class"));

        });
        skill[sw.swd[m]] = swObj;
    }

var data = " ";
    $.each(skill, function(key, value) {            
        data += '<li>' + key + ':' + value + '</li>';                       
    });
```

I need to remove the bullet which appears before the list appears. 
My output looks like:

- 
- Vehicle: Train, Bus, Car
- Veg: Onion, Potato, Tomato

I want the output by removing the first bullet on top. Guys could someone help me out with this issue?

Comment: just use if(key !=""  && value !="") {      data += '<li>' + key + ':' + value + '</li>';         }  before concatenation .

Comment: you can do this withh css too. li:empty { display:none;}

Answer (score 1):

just use

`if(key !="" && value !="") { data += '<li>' + key + ':' + value + '</li>'; }`

Comment: do you have any other answer for me?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
  var data = " ";
    $.each(skill, function(key, value) {    
         if (value === " " || value === null || value === undefined || value === "" || typeof (value ) === "undefined")   // Advanced null check + white space check
        //if(  value ) { // normal null check
           data += '<li>' + key + ':' + value + '</li>';              
        }         
    });
```

No need to check/validate key, as that will never be null when you are using $.each

Note: If in case your values is white space, this validation will not work, and you need to add that also to this list.

Comment: is it a white space getting rendered, instead of which we are mistaking it to null?

Comment: Yes it is a white space getting rendered Sarin. Sorry for the late information. I checked it just now

Comment: You need to filter for that exact value, which is getting displayed as blank in your application. Use chrome debugger or firebug to debug and identify that, and add that into validation to avoid.

Also if possible share the value of variable "skill". With out that value, all We are doing here is searching in darkness.

Comment: Also share HTML of "input[name='swt'", because, that is where the values lies, which exactly we need to know.

Comment: Can you help me out Sarin?

Comment: SHare your HTML

Comment: I have added the HTML part. Check it out

Comment: What you posted is not enough, we are ready to help you, but you need to share if we have to. All I want to see is what is that value that comming as empty in your code, and the source of that value is your html checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
 var sw = {};
    var favorite = [];
    $.each($("input[name='swt']:checked"), function() {
        favorite.push($(this).val());           
    });
    sw.swd = favorite;

var skill= {};
    for (var m = 0; m < favorite.length; m++) {
        var swObj = [];
        $.each($('input[name="' + sw.swd[m] + '"]:checked'), function() {                
            swObj.push($(this).attr("class"));

        });
        skill[sw.swd[m]] = swObj;
    }

var data = " ";
    $.each(skill, function(key, value) {            
       
   data += '<li>' + key + ':' + value + '</li>';                     
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="row list-group checked-list-box col-xs-3">
<li class="list-group-item tree">  <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="Train" name="swt">Train</li></ul>
```

Comment: Can you please share the whole code including the ul tag.

Comment: please user this html 
<li class="list-group-item tree">  <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="Train" name="swt">Train</li>

Comment: No your li tag is not properly closed, 

I checked your code on my machine

Comment: Remove the trim section, I check your whole code, there is only one mistake in that. You did not close 'li' tag properly. 
Check this screen shot:-
http://i.prntscr.com/308809f1f0a3452dadfd348e5342147f.png

Comment: replace code with

$('#list').append('<li style="list-style: none;" class="list-group-item tree">  <input type="checkbox"  name="swt">'+ "Train" + '</li>');